# how to concatenate two lists objects and join string objects in list

Tags: python

How do I concatenate two lists in Python?
example:
input:

```
    x=['saeed']
    y=['gharif']
```

output expected:

```
    z=['saeedgharif']
```

Comment: By reading and processing a  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ I would concentrate on strings and lists and (maybe list comprehensions)...

Answer (score 0):

You have two lists, each with a single element, so you can make a new list by concatenating the `[0]` element of each list

```
>>> z = [x[0] + y[0]]
>>> z
['saeedgharif']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip` and a list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
x=['saeed']
y=['gharif']

print( [i+v for i,v in zip(x, y)] )
```

**Output:**

```
['saeedgharif']
```

Answer (score 0):

[Join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) is way more readable, and just use `+` to combine both lists.

```
x=['saeed']
y=['gharif']
z=''.join(x+y)
```